# nested attributes wont update rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, nested-attributes

This has stumped me for most of the day. I am trying to create a nested form for a join table.

- a job has_many job locations
- a job has_many locations through job locations
- a job location belongs to a job and a location
- a job location has many
- a location has many job locations
- a location has many jobs through locations

I want the user to select from a possible 5 locations, which I have in an array with their respective id's. The user selects these locations from the edit action of the job page, so I grab the job id by doing this:

```
@job.job_locations.build
```

This is where I am stuck.

I have added to my job model,   `accepts_nested_attributes_for :job_locations` which is below in order of the associations.

and then my form

```
     =simple_form_for edit_admin_job_path(@job) do |f|
      =f.simple_fields_for :job_locations do |p|
        =p.input :location_id, collection: @common_locations_array
        =f.submit
```

What am I missing?

I am using Rails 4, haml, and simple form.

## Update

Could it be my collection in the nested form. the collection contains all the information of the location, not just the id. Shouldnt i be setting the input value? How would I do that?

added controller actions

```
def edit
    unless @job = Job.find_by(id: params[:id])
      flash[:error] = "Job could not be found"

      if @job_subject
        redirect_to(admin_polymorphic_jobs_path(@job_subject))
      else
        redirect_to root_path # points to /admin/searches/new
      end
    end
    @job.job_locations.build
    @location = Location.new
    @client = @job.client 
    @locations_grouped_hash = JobLocation.group(:location_id).distinct.count(:id)
    @common_locations_hash = @locations_grouped_hash.sort_by { |k, v| v }.reverse.first(5).to_h
    @common_locations_array = []
    @common_locations_hash.each do |k, v| 
      @common_locations_array << Location.find(k)
    end


    @job_types = JobType.get_all_job_types
  end



  # PUT-PATCH /admin/jobs/:id                        admin_job_path
  # PUT-PATCH /admin/clients/:client_id/jobs/:id     admin_client_job_path
  # PUT-PATCH /admin/contacts/:contact_id/jobs/:id   admin_contact_job_path
  def update
    @job = Job.find_by(id: params[:id])
      was_frozen = @job.workflow_frozen?
      
      @job.assign_attributes(job_params)
      job_changes = @job.changes
      will_be_frozen = @job.workflow_frozen?  
      # this MUST be atomic!
      ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
        @job.freeze_stock! if (will_be_frozen && !was_frozen)
        if @job.save
          flash[:success] = "attributes updated"
        else
          flash[:error] = "Couldn't update the job. Please check for errors."
          @job_types = JobType.get_all_job_types
          render('admin/jobs/edit') and return
        end
        @job.unfreeze_stock! if (!will_be_frozen && was_frozen)
      end


      # We clear the associations before proceeding, because even
      # if params[:locations] is missing, it just means that the
      # user has deselected all of them before submitting
      @job.locations.clear
  
      # ...and here we re-add only the selecred ones
      if params[:locations]
        params[:locations].each do |loc_id|
          this_location = Location.find_by(id: loc_id)
          @job.locations << this_location if this_location
          # we can safely assume that all of these locations already belong to the client
        end
      end
  
      # OLD - replaced by NEW, below:
      #    We clear the associations before proceeding, because even
      #    if params[:contacts] is missing, it just means that the
      #    user has deselected all of them before submitting
      # @job.contacts.clear
      if params[:contacts]
        # NEW
        # first we need to remove the "not selected" contacts
        new_contact_ids = params[:contacts].map { |item| item.to_i }
        @job.contacts.each do |associated_contact|
          unless new_contact_ids.include?(associated_contact.id)
            @job.contacts.delete(associated_contact)
          end
        end
  
        # and now we add the selected ones
        # (we assume that all of these contacts already belong to the client)
        new_contact_ids.each do |new_contact_id|
          this_contact = Contact.find_by(id: new_contact_id)
          begin
            @job.contacts << this_contact if this_contact
          rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid
            # the contact was already assigned
          end
        end
      else
        # all unchecked, let's remove them all
        @job.contacts.clear
      end
      AdminActivity.job_details_updated!(current_admin, @job, job_changes)
      redirect_to edit_admin_job_path(@job)
    
    
  end
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want `= p.input :location_id, collection: @common_locations_array` instead of `=f.input` since you're updating the `location_id` for `job_location`.

**UPDATE:**

After a chat with @user3868832, he had to update:

`=simple_form_for edit_admin_job_path(@job) do |f|`

to `=simple_form_for :job do |f|`

which allowed his form to actually hit the `update` action.

Comment: Are you getting any errors or is the form submitting and the `job_location` for the specified `@job` just isn't updating? Also, please post your controller action that receives this form's request.

Comment: No errors. the page refreshes and no entry is created in the job_location table. what could it be? would my server logs be of any use?

Comment: Please post the controller action that receives the form request.

Comment: Are you sure the form is hitting your `update` action? This line: `=simple_form_for edit_admin_job_path(@job) do |f|` suggests that the form would be submitted to the `edit` action, not the `update` action, which I imagine is the intended behavior. I've never used `simple_form` so I'm going off my knowledge of Rails forms. Is there a reason why you're not simply using `=simple_form_for @job do |f|`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59768/discussion-between-mmichael-and-user3868832).

Comment: That's a really good point actually. I had tried that, but it threw up the error 'undefined method `job_path''. but your point makes sense. how else would I do it though?

Comment: We're better off discussing this over chat. Please click the link from my previous comment.